# Multi-level sidebar menu like Glazed Main

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, sidebar

I recently ran into this GIF of a sidebar menu: 
https://www.sooperthemes.com/sites/default/files/documentation-files/main-menu-mobile-2.gif?fid=925

I have completely fallen in love with the fact that the entire menu is exchanged for the child menu, which in theory could work with an unlimited amount of levels in the menu.

How is this navbar made, or does a tutorial or a Codepen exist with something similar? It would be greatly appreciated.

I could ofcourse use Javascript to hide the "parent-menu" onClick and add an item to the top breadcrumb menu, but surely a cleaner solution exists?